# Is there a way to specify different DNS lookup for each request with okhttp?

Tags: dns, okhttp, resolver

I want to distribute requests by some parameters.
For example when using http DNS.

Is there a way to specify different DNS resolver for each request?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Because of [connection reuse](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-connection/#connection-reuse) there is no guarantee that DNS will be used before starting your request.  To strictly achieve what you are asking for you should fork a new client with a distinct DNS implementation for each cluster of requests.

```
  val client1 = client.newBuilder().dns(externalDns).build()
  val client2 = client.newBuilder().dns(intranetDns).build()
```

But if the split is by hostname, then you could just override the common DNS and make it do whatever you need.

You should confirm the behaviour you want is happening with an event listener.

Docs on [connections](https://square.github.io/okhttp/connections/) and [events logging](https://square.github.io/okhttp/events/).

A great [post on debugging](https://medium.com/booking-com-development/maximizing-okhttp-connection-reuse-b1f0ad6ec66c) into connection reuse.

Comment: I see now and use HostnameVerifier to avoid the problem. But it is too ugly:(